# Loop Is Repeating Same Values

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function where I have 3 parameters: start, step and stop. These will set the start of the loop, how much to go up by and when to stop.

I managed to make it show however the loop is repeating the same numbers until it finishes the task.

I need to show the result in an array so for example if I have a starting position at 0, going up by 2 and stopping at 10, I would to return [0,2,4,6,8,10].

```js
function range(start, step, stop) {

  var rando = [];
  
  for (i = start; i <=stop; i = i + step) {
  
    rando.push(i);
    console.log(rando);
  }
}

range(0, 2, 10);
```

Comment: Use `var` or `let`.

Comment: I think it is just because your console.log statement is inside your loop?

Comment: replace `for (i = start; i <=stop; i = i + step)` with `for (let i = start; i <=stop; i = i + step)`

Comment: `I would to return` - your function doesn't return anything

Comment: @mhodges I know, it was only a recomendation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply move your console.log statement outside of your for loop:

When you have the log statement inside the loop, it will log out the contents of the array at every iteration. Since you only want to print out the complete array once, put the console.log statement after the for loop has finished.

```js
function range(start, step, stop) {

  var rando = [];
  
  for (var i = start; i <=stop; i = i + step) {
    rando.push(i);
  }
  console.log(rando);
}

range(0, 2, 10);
```

As many others have mentioned, an additional suggestion for you would be to put the `var` or `let` keyword in front of your `i` variable in your for loop so that you don't accidentally set or override something on the global scope.

Comment: @JaromandaX There are legitimate use cases for GNDN functions. We don't know what the OP intends to do. The question is about not logging out the array multiple times. Extrapolating intent beyond that is unnecessary

Comment: @JaromandaX Ehhh, yeah it *could*. Based off the rest of the verbiage in the post, I am writing that off as the OP doesn't know what words to use in which contexts. Since there is no assignment statement when they call the function, returning the array is useless anyway.

Comment: @JaromandaX Well, it was a legitimate comment, I just personally didn't think it applied to what the OP was trying to do, but, since we haven't heard from the OP, we can't really know for sure

Answer (score 1):

You should return the `result` array and remove the `console.log` from the `for` loop.

*I'ts a good practice to declare variables by using `var` or `let`.*

```
var rando = [];
for (var i = start; i <= stop; i = i + step) {
  rando.push(i);
}
return rando;
```

Something like this:

```js
function range(start, step, stop) {
  var rando = [];
  for (var i = start; i <= stop; i = i + step) {
    rando.push(i);
  }
  return rando;
}
console.log(range(0, 2, 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

you're printing your array every iteration of the loop. let the loop finish, then call `console.log`

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code, broken down:

You are defining a function (as you said) with three parameters, `start`, `step`, and `stop`.

You then create an empty array, `rando`.

For each number `i` from `start` to `stop` (counting by `step`), you append `i` to `rando` and print out `rando`.

This causes your array to be printed out more than once, each time with a new number at the end.

To fix this, you have two options, depending on what you want.

1. Print out the list *after* the loop.
2. Print out `i` inside the loop.

The first result will print out the array when all of the numbers are added, and the second will print out each number sequentially.

Comment: one thing to note is, in the console (in a browser console, not a SO snippet output, nor nodejs output), the array will look like it has all the values even after the first console.log - this is because console "lies" :p

Comment: Is that due to javascript being asynchronous? (sorry for being a little off-topic, you have me interested)

Comment: no, it's due to what console.log outputs :p it outputs a reference to the array, so it's like arr1 = arr2, bot arr1 and arr2 reference the same data ... changes to arr1[0] will change arr2[0] ... and any output in the console will also reflect these changes

Comment: @iPhoenix Not that it has to do with your answer, but since you asked: JavaScript, by nature is not asynchronous. Asynchronicity is an opt-in feature that is only standard on a few native functions (i.e. setTimeout, setInterval, etc.)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I was under the impression that console.log was async, but through further research, it appears it does not have a standard, and it doesn't really matter.